# Ios recording Live mic Data cant record and send?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecViewController: UIViewController,AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var recBtn: UIButton!

    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    var result: NSData?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.recBtn.setTitle("RECORDING", for: .normal)
    }

    @IBAction func recBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {

        session.sessionPreset = .medium

        let mic = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
        var mic_input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!

        let audio_output = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
        audio_output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

        do {
            mic_input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: mic!)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if session.inputs.isEmpty {
            self.session.addInput(mic_input)
            session.addOutput(audio_output)
        }

        session.startRunning()

    }
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        let block = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        var length = 0
        var data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>? = nil

        var status = CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer(block!, 0, nil, &length, &data)    // TODO: check for errors

        result = NSData(bytesNoCopy: data!, length: length, freeWhenDone: false)
    }

    @IBAction func playBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
        // Storing the ns data and trying to play with following code but it dosent play cant hear a thing
        do {
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: result as! Data )
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }

}
```

i am using this code to record live data from mic but when i press the rec Button nothing happens it neither records nor it goes to delegate and print so how to solve this ? (Solved)

I have updated the code and when i trying to play that ns data via av audio players it dosen't plays anything how to solve this?

Comment: Is anything actually captured in the `catch` block? As the code sample you've provided simply returns if there's an error.

If you catch the error that's possibly created, you should be able to figure out a bit more as to why this is failing.

Comment: @MultiColourPixel no on console no error is printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like your `audio_output` is actually retained by anything outside the scope of the `recBtnAction` method. It's quite likely that your session is being discarded by the time you leave the method, therefore not capturing anything for you.

---

*Edit*

Having had a play with the sample code that you provided, it seems that your actual issue is that the delegate method you have used is of the wrong signature.

It should be:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
}
```

Comment: So how to fix this ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: do {
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: result as! Data )
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
        catch{
            print(
                "Error")

        }

Comment: I am using this to play the audio but it dosent work

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you're trying to play back in the very same method that you're attempting to capture the data? It might be a good idea to actually capture some data first, stop the capture and then attempt to play that back.
Putting everything into one method makes it hard to figure out just what aspect may or may not be working

Comment: ohh I was doing The Same I captured the data and Played it on different button action but it wouldn't play no generation of sound the audio player.play code you can assume is onother button action i have corrected the code according to this

Comment: You should probably create a new question for this!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968519/how-to-play-nsdata-or-buffer-on-iphone Please check this out ?